# German POW Camp records for WWI

Tags: military-records, germany, world-war-1

A British Prisoner was said to have been informed by the Commandant of Doberitz POW camp
of his award of the Victoria Cross..Where would I start to look for records from this camp ?

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy.SE! It is always helpful to include known names and dates in your questions so that others can help you to locate resources.

Answer (score 7):

The [*Deutsche Dienststelle (WASt)*](http://www.dd-wast.de/) holds

> *Approximately 1.500.000 files (residue) on foreign P.o.Ws. in German custody.* ([Assets of the Deutsche Dienststelle](http://www.dd-wast.de/e_archiv.htm))

I wrote a little bit on using records from the Deutsche Dienststelle in my answer to [*How to find information on German soldiers from World War I and World War II?*](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-to-find-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii/3917#3917). In a nutshell: You’ll send a request using the online form (available in German, English and French). You have to pay at least 8 Euro per answer page and wait for up to a year. They will answer you in German. You should give it a try.

The archives of the [International Prisoners-of-War Agency](http://grandeguerre.icrc.org/) are now available. They hold  500,000 pages of lists and six million index cards regarding prisoners of war (WW I).

Please see also The National Archives: *[Looking for records of a British prisoner of war c.1790-1919](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/records/looking-for-person/britishpowfirstworldwar.htm)* for a general overview.

I can’t comment on military sources in Britain, but I have serious doubts that there are other archives in Germany beside the *Deutsche Dienststelle* holding individual records.

When searching the internet for the camp refer to the query *Gefangenenlager Döberitz* for German results. Martin Conrath published several documents on the history of the Döberitzer Heide (*[Zur Geschichte der Döberitzer Heide](http://www.mc-mk.de/GdDH/inhalte.html)*), which can be found online and also contain information on the German barracks and POW camps. Maybe you’ll discover your ancestor or his name somewhere. See also [*The Döberitz Gazette: An International Magazine for the Kriegsgefangene Interned at Döberitz*](http://www.gutenberg-e.org/steuer/steuer.ch07a.html#). Additional information on this publication are available on [doberitz.com](http://www.doberitz.com/)

Comment: I have looked at Deutsche Dienststelle and even though they say they have information on POW.s their search form seems to be only for WWII soldiers. or am I not looking in the right place ?

Comment: @Iain I see no such limitation in their [request form](http://www.dd-wast.de/suchstart.html). You can detail your query using *purpose* and *additional information*.

Answer (score 2):

You may be referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidney_Godley:

> Originally it was thought that he had been killed, but some time later
> it was found that he was a prisoner of war in a camp called Delotz at
> Dallgow-Döberitz. It was in the camp that he was informed that he had
> been awarded the Victoria Cross. Godley left the camp in 1918 after
> the guards fled their posts. He received the actual medal from King
> George V, at Buckingham Palace, on 15 February 1919.