# Returning German air force record book to family of Walter Schamberger of Sonneberg?

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-2, thuringia, air-force

I would like to find relatives of Walter Schamberger born 15/01/1910 in Oberlind, now part of the city of Sonneberg.

He was a flight leader in the German air force.

I am in possession of his record book and would like to return it to his family.

Answer (score 4):

What about scanning the record book for public access and returning the  book to [Deutsche Dienststelle](https://www.dd-wast.de/en/home.html) (WASt), a federal organization maintaining records on servicemen? They can use the content to provide information to interested ancestors and other parties (please see also my answers on [*How to find information on German soldiers from World War I and World War II?*](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-to-find-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii/3917) and [*Returning World War I era German dog tags?*](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6714/returning-world-war-i-era-german-dog-tags/6718)).

Otherwise you can use address directories like [Das Örtliche](http://www.dasoertliche.de/) to contact possible family members. Please note that *Schamberger* is a common name in this border Region of Thuringia/Bavaria. Returning the book to the wrong Schamberger or some uninterested ancestor has the risk of the record being destroyed, getting lost or being put on eBay. I’d contact WASt instead.