# How to return NSDAP Membership Book to family of Adolf-Georg Werner?

Tags: germany, world-war-2

My Father was an American soldier during the Battle of the Bulge in WWII.  Among his things I have found a red NSDAP Membership booklet with the photo and information of an Adolf-Georg Werner.  It is a small red booklet with his photo and stamps.  I know this is a very long shot but I wanted to try and return this to any of his family.

What steps can I take to locate his family?

Comment: Hi Bonnie, welcome. I tweaked your question a little bit to make it more suitable for this format. I hope you get some useful recommendations as to how to proceed with this. Out of curiosity, do you know how the booklet came to be in your father's possession?

Comment: I collect these and i have some knowledge on them. There are pages inside that give the owner's date of birth, town and where the book was issued. Do you still have the book?

Answer (score 4):

There were two similar questions, but on military records: [*Returning German air force record book to family of Walter Schamberger of Sonneberg?*](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/8135/returning-german-air-force-record-book-to-family-of-walter-schamberger-of-sonneb?rq=1) and [*Returning World War I era German dog tags?*](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6714/returning-world-war-i-era-german-dog-tags/6718#6718)

My answer given there doesn’t apply here, as were are not talking about military records. I am not aware of any archive that is interested in such membership booklets (except from prominent historical figures).

Locating the family:

*Werner* is a very common name. You could look for the birth place in the booklet or any information on places of residence in there. Then you might check directories like [Das Örtliche](http://www.dasoertliche.de/) to contact possible ancestors (people with that surname) in that area. I consider a match unlikely.

I would scan it, post it to Flickr with the name and some additional information (so it can be found) and keep it as an obscure detail of my family’s history.

Keep in mind, that getting your Nazi party membership booklet back might not be in everybody’s interest as well.

PS: There is also a small, but well curated family history project in Germany that makes scans of family documents available to the public: http://www.dilibra.com/ Maybe they are interested in the scans.