# Where to find records relating to people Missing in Action (MIA) during World War 2?

Tags: germany, world-war-2, holocaust

Recently I was given the email address to contact concerning the internment of my Great Uncle in Dachau concentration camp.

The person who sent me the information was very helpful and sent me all information regarding my Great Uncle.

Unfortunately, I did not make copies of the documents and my computer crashed and I lost everything.

The information I received came from the Washington Holocaust Museum but I was directed to a particular person and that name I cannot for the life of me remember.

I did look at the site and was overwhelmed and just punching in my Great Uncles details gave me nothing.

I also lost documentation of my other Great Uncle who was missing in action in Stalingrad during the same war.

Any suggestions how I can retrieve my documents?

---

I am also looking for another relative who is the son of another Uncle who fought on the Alps in Mt Cassino and is said to be living in Gross Gerau.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  While you are waiting for an answer, some of the answers to related questions about [tag:WWII] and [tag:Germany] displayed on the right side of the screen may have information that could help. Thank you for being considerate of [our guidelines](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) which say "You must not include here in any circumstances information (including name, date and place of birth or any other details) that would allow identification of any living (or possibly) living individual by somebody reading this site."

Comment: Likewise welcome to G&FH SE! Some of our protocols can take a little getting used to but I think the focus of this question should be to try and relocate the source of the information for your first great uncle.  It sounds like this may also get you the documentation for the second great uncle.  I think seeking "the son of another Uncle" may be better asked as a separate question.  In all cases if you can mention the year (or approximate year) of their birth (and no other details) then that will let us assess whether privacy is a concern (as Jan mentions above).

Comment: Can you also clarify your question as to whether they survived their internment as I would assume there would assume there would be additional documents. Directly related to your question, a lot of people say "my computer died and I lost everything." Being I dabble computer forensics that is unlikely, you may be able to recover it and if valuable enough there are services that will do it for you but it is expensive. But like Jan & Poly said narrowing down the scope of your question would be helpful.

Comment: My Great Uncle survived his internment in Dachau and was last seen in Berlin.

Comment: And was released in 1945 at the end of the war.

Comment: Please post separate questions, this one is on a concentration camp survivor, a German war casualty and a German soldier surviving the war. There is no generic answer to three biographies. Please check also [this question](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-to-find-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii/3917#3917)

Comment: I agree with the advice offered by @lejonet.  If you decide to "split" your question into three questions the way to do this is to use the **edit** button beneath it to edit out the parts not related to the first ancestor, and then to ask two new questions related to the second and third ancestors respectively.

Comment: While I am unable to answer your question about the person to contact, I am curious about your computer and the fact that you "lost everything". Were you able to have someone remove the hard drive and try to recover your information? If not, you may not have lost all of your hard work and this may be a viable and inexpensive way to recover your files.

Answer (score 1):

The most comprehensive database I found regarding people part of the German army (Wehrmacht) that died or were missing during WW2 is the [Gräbersuche online](https://www.volksbund.de/en/graebersuche.html) of Volksbund Deutsche Kriegsgräberfürsorge e. V.