# Locating heirs of killed german soldier

Tags: germany, world-war-2

I have a friend that has the German Lugar, Helmet, and Bayonet from a German soldier that this American soldier had killed during WWII and would like to locate heirs to return these items to them. We have misplaced his dog tag and will try to find them. His name is in his helmet.  These items were given personally by him to a Cuban soldier after the war. If we locate the name can you help us locate any of his heirs. The owner of these items was married to a Cuban National so I know it is authentic information. The Lugar is locked in a Bank safe deposit box.

I think his family should have these personal items.

Comment: With Lugar you mean a pistol (Luger)?
See also https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/15914/10823

Comment: Please note that this site is not about "Locating identifiable living individuals" and you say "If we locate the name can you help us locate any of his heirs."  If that becomes your question then it will be off-topic.

Comment: One thing to note is that due to privacy laws in Germany, you can't just go around looking for living family. Registrars offices will require a lawful reason to give you any information. This requires either a direct ancestral relationship or something like an executor of a will to track down beneficiaries.