# Getting military records on WW2 Luftwaffe personnel?

Tags: military-records, germany, world-war-2

My father and his brother were both in the Luftwaffe.

I am trying to obtain their military records, and in the case of my fathers brother, the circumstances surrounding his death in a plane crash in 1936.

I see references to records for german soldiers, but I do not see any references regarding finding this information for Luftwaffe personnel.

Where would I look for this?

Answer (score 5):

Please see my answer on [*How to find information on German soldiers from World War I and World War II?*](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-to-find-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii/3917#3917). The *Deutsche Dienststelle* (WASt, Deutsche Dienststelle für die Benachrichtigung der nächsten Angehörigen von Gefallenen der ehemaligen deutschen Wehrmacht) [has also the records for members of the Luftwaffe](https://www.dd-wast.de/de/unterlagen/akten-und-karteimaterial.html). Additional information on officers might also be [available from the Bundesarchiv](https://www.bundesarchiv.de/benutzung/sachbezug/personenbezogen_genealogie/01306/index.html.de)  in Freiburg/Br. They have also military court material, if needed.

[Officer Career Summaries](http://ww2.dk/lwoffz.html) are also provided on a private website.