# What are these abbreviations in a Verlustliste (zurueckgeh, krgef, A)?

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-1

I'm looking at Verlustlisten 1. Weltkrieg, [page 22.835: Peter Robert](http://des.genealogy.net/search/show/4367541) (Bremerhaven) on genealogy.net.  In the entry, it says "zurueckgeh."  What does this mean?  I know other entries say things like "leicht verwundet" (lightly wounded) or "gefallen" (died).  Would "zurueckgehen" mean that he went home as a result of his wounds?

One more abbreviation:  the entry says "krgef" - Kriegsgefangener, prisoner of war, no?  And this is followed by the letter "A".  What might the "A" mean?[image: Verlustlisten]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means that he was *retained* (“**zurückgeh**.” = “zurückgehalten”) by a neutral country until now (“**bish**.” = “bisher”), [as this list of abbreviations for the navy lists](http://files.genealogy.net/verlustlisten/10892.jpeg) suggests. Now he is *prisoner of war* (“**krgef**.” = “kriegsgefangen”). “**A**” could indicate that this information was received from a foreign country (“Ausland“), as “A.N.” is elsewhere used for “Auslands-Nachricht” (message from abroad). It could also refer to *American* captivity, as “krgef. F.” is used for POW in France or “krgef. E.” for POW in England according to the abbreviation list.

There are also entries like

- *bish. v. krgef., v. u. zurückgeh.* (until now wounded and POW, [now] wounded and retained)
- *bish. krgef., zurückgeh.*  (until now POW, [now] retained)

There is an earlier (1915) record of someone with the same name (Peter, Robert from Bremerhaven): http://des.genealogy.net/search/show/918673 He is marked as retained there.

I would assume that the ship was in a neutral harbor and the servicemen where later passed over to a enemy country or the former neutral country declared war on Germany.

The Deutsche Dienststelle (WASt) holds 1.6 million records on German navy men ([Marine-Archiv](https://www.dd-wast.de/de/unterlagen/marinearchiv.html)), maybe you can get more information from them. See [my answer on *How to find information on German soldiers from World War I and World War II?*](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-to-find-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii/3917#3917) for more details.

For other abbreviations in the Verlustlisten related to casualties please see [**Reference Key for Injuries for WWI German Casualty Lists?**](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/11885/reference-key-for-injuries-for-wwi-german-casualty-lists/11886#11886)

Comment: A poster on another forum has suggested that the "A" indicates he was an American prisoner of war -- would you agree with that?

Comment: @ewormuth This is a good idea, as as “krgef. F.” is used for POW in France or “krgef. E.” for POW in England according to the abbreviation list. I added it to my answer. Do you consider contacting the Deutsche Dienststelle? I am curious what they might have on a sailor from the Imperial Navy.

Comment: I'm looking at the Deutsche Dienstelle, and it will take me some time to figure out how to use it -- though I can read German with some effort, this site is quite difficult for me.  Am I correct that they don't have a search function, but rather you submit a request to them for information?

Comment: @ewormuth There are no records online. You send a request and they will reply after several months with a letter. There is an English version of the page, please see https://www.dd-wast.de/en/tracing-request/private-matters-research.html.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I saw the English page but felt I needed to get more out of the German pages to understand how to use the site.