# Reference Key for Injuries for WWI German Casualty Lists?

Tags: germany, world-war-1

Is anyone aware of a quick reference or list of injuries / cause of death for [world-war-1](/questions/tagged/world-war-1) German Casualty lists, such as in the following example.

This doesn't appear to be just a death list, but any injury from translating a few but also seems to be broad.

I do not read or speak German, and Google Translate for like 'gefallen' says 'like' which doesn't make sense and also the 'bermenbet' I tried doesn't translate.. it could at least partially be my reading of German but would think it would be expedite my readings of these with a key.

[image]

I also looked at the very broad [WWI and WWII German Soldier question](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-to-find-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii) and didn't see something jumping out in the links there as well as some other website's including [Family Search's German Military Record](https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/Germany_Military_Records) page.

Is there a key to the casualty lists and more specifically the injuries / deaths associated with them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/9542/1006 ?  It's probably best to leave both questions on the site -- some people will find the English one and some with title in German.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Casualties in the Verlustlisten include the following keys and abbreviations:

- **t** or **†** (“tot”) – dead
- **gefallen** – killed in action
- **† an seinen schweren Wunden** – died because of his serious injuries
- **v.** or **verw.** (“verwundet”) – wounded
- **l.v.** (“leicht verwundet”) – slightly wounded
- **s.v.** or **schw. verw.** (“schwer verwundet”) – seriously wounded
- **l.v.b.d.Tr.** (“leicht verwundet, bei der Truppe”) – slightly wounded, but with the troops
- **Gefgsch.** (“Gefangenschaft”) – POW
- **G +** (“Gefangenschaft †”) – died as POW
- **A.N.** (“Auslands-Nachricht”) – message from abroad
- **vermißt** – missing in action
- **bisher vermißt, verwundet** – missing until now, wounded
- **† infolge Krankheit** – died because of illness
- **Res. Feldlaz.** ("Reserve Feldlazarett") – Reserve field hospital or aid station
- **zum 3. Male verwundet** – wounded for the 3rd time
- **durch Unfall schwer verletzt** – seriously injured because of an accident

Comment: Please add other terms/abbreviations you like to see translated/explained.