# Linking handwritten numbers on an arm band to German WWII military records

Tags: germany, military-records

I have an arm band my father brought back while fighting for the Canadian army. It has hand written numbers on it. Is there any way to trace the numbers in German army records?

Comment: Hi Charles, welcome to our site. Could you please show us a photo of this arm band and its numbers? It could be everything. Dog tags ("Erkennungsmarken") have specific numbers that can be linked to records. There a also postal numbers ("Feldpostnummern"). Without a photo I can't give you a definite answer. Please see my introduction on German army records: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-to-find-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii/3917#3917