# Where were Bavarian soldiers of E/R 14 imprisoned on farm in Normandy?

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-1, france

Father entered Bavarian army in WW1 in Germany on August 30, 1914.

He was in E/R 14, taken prisoner and sent to Normandy, France on a farm.

Where was the farm?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] because our site works differently from other bulletin boards, discussion forums and Q&A sites that you may be used to.  In order to attract potential answerers to your question I recommend that you use the **edit** button beneath it to add a few more details.  For example, can you perhaps provide a link to "E/R 14", or if you are happy to provide your father's name and date of birth that could be very helpful.  If you are concerned about privacy, there is no need to include his name, but it may make answers harder to provide.

Comment: Have you studied the [Kriegsranglisten and Kriegsstammrollen](http://www.ancestry.de/cs/de/bayern-erster-weltkrieg-startseite) for more details on his military career? Which unit do you mean bei "E/R 14"? Do you mean the [Königlich Bayerische Reserve-Infanterie-Regiment Nr. 14](http://wiki-de.genealogy.net/KB_RIR_14)? You should study the Verlustlisten (also for prisoners) and the Prisoners of the First World War Archive. See this answer for details: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-to-find-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii/3917#3917.