# WW1 German military service in 124th infantry regiment

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-1

Would like to learn the military service for German Jewish soldier, Caro W. Naphtali, of the Imperial German Infantry 124th Regiment?

Comment: Please see my answer on http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-to-find-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii on how to research WWI military personnel from Germany. Could you please give some additional information (place and date of birth), maybe I can help you a little more then.

Answer (score 5):

Please see my answer on [*How to find information on German soldiers from World War I and World War II?*](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-to-find-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii) for general research strategies.

I did not find Caro Naphtali in the *Verlustlisten*, so – if the spelling is correct – I assume he did not die during the war and wasn’t injured or taken prisoner.

There is secondary literature available for the unit, which should give a general idea on battle participations e.g.: 
 Wolters, Gerhard: *Das Infanterie-Regiment König Wilhelm I. (6. württ.) No. 124 im Weltkrieg 1914-1918*" - Stuttgart, C. Belsersche Verlagsbuchhandlung, 1921 ([online](http://digital.wlb-stuttgart.de/sammlungen/sammlungsliste/werksansicht/?no_cache=1&tx_dlf%5Bid%5D=3238&tx_dlf%5Bpage%5D=1))

The regiment was from Wurttemberg and belonged to the XIIIth army corps. The musterrolls are available via the [Hauptstaatsarchiv Stuttgart](http://www.landesarchiv-bw.de/web/47272) (details: https://www2.landesarchiv-bw.de/ofs21/olf/struktur.php?bestand=6101&klassi=001&anzeigeKlassi=001.002). Contact them for a reproduction of Mr Naphtali’s entry.