# Looking for evidence of my grandfather's German citizenship?

Tags: germany, military-records, birth-records, world-war-2, silesia

I am looking for records of my grandfather, Ernest Paul Wolf, born on 1.11.1899 in Strehlen, Silesia, son of Fiedrich Wolf and Auguste Krause, both German.

During WWII he was a civilian. I need his birth certificate, WWII registration records, or other evidence of his citizenship.

My father was born 1929 in Uruguay, and he was recruited when he was 16 years old during the last three months of war in Germany. He lived in Germany from 1931 to 1950. I also would like to know if it is possible to find any WWII records of my father.

My goal is to obtain German citizenship.

Comment: Hi & welcome to G&FH SE. City of Strehlen or Kreis Strehlen? 'Registered at WWII' how? military, civilian, refugee? When did he leave Silesia? What religion? Local civil and Lutheran records were mostly destroyed in WWII and Catholic records are in Polish archives. Contempory copies may exist elsewhere, depending on date and origin, but you need to add details for better answers.

Comment: Please ask a separate question about your father but be aware that our privacy policy at the [help/on-topic] does not allow his name and date of birth to be shown here without evidence of decease because he was born less than 100 years ago.

Comment: Hi Marina, thank you for adding further details to your question! I have edited your question somewhat to make it clearer regarding your goal to obtain German citizenship. If I've changed anything incorrectly feel free to modify it again yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If Mr Wolf served in the German military during WW II you can contact *Deutsche Dienststelle (WASt)* for a compiled service record. You just need the name and birth date. Please see my answer on [*How to find information on German soldiers from World War I and World War II?*](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-to-find-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii/3917#3917) for details.

Birth certificates and similar records from the civil registry office (Standesamt) are not available according to [this great overview on Silesian records](http://www.christoph-www.de/kbsilesia2.html). Maybe they were destroyed during WW II. Catholic church records covering the relevant time are available at the church archive in Wrocław (Breslau), but baptisms are limited to military personnel.