# Prussian army records before 1890

Tags: 19th-century, military-records, prussia

My greatgrandfather was ethnic Polish but was in the Prussian army prior to 1890. How can I find his records?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Your question is very brief, so to assist those trying to help you, I would recommend using the [edit] button beneath your question to provide additional information like how you know he was in the Prussian Army.  Is it from a document or just family knowledge?  Usually the more details you provide the more you are likely to be able to interest our volunteers to help work your problem.

Answer (score 4):

There are almost no records left, the *Heeresarchiv Potsdam* was bombed in April 1945 and destroyed by fire. The records destroyed include also those of servicemen of WWI (please see also [*How to find information on German soldiers from World War I and World War II?*](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-to-find-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii/3917#3917))

Please specify your question (name, time of duty, e.g. photos), maybe secondary literature might help (but this is unlikely as well).