# Seeking German military service records for Jozef Mühlgay (or his brothers) of Bavaria?

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-1, austria, bavaria

I've been trying to figure out if my great-grandfather, Jozef Mühlgay, or his brothers were called up for the Great War.

What I know is that at the time of the war, my great-grandfather and his brothers were living in Fürth, Bavaria, and of military age. However, very little family history has survived with regards to this branch of the family, at least as far as concrete facts are concerned.

Are there any mentions (likely in the Bavarian or Austrian records) of any members of the Mühlgay family serving in the military?

Comment: Have you reviewed the questions tagged world-war-1 and Germany? They should give you a good idea where to start to ask a more specific question. http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-war-1+germany

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl, I would (and have) check(ed) some of the links in <http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-to-find-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii>, but my German is nearly non-existent.

Comment: @NoahfromFrankfurt You can check Bavarian service records (1914-1918)  on Ancestry with an English interface. If you find something we can help with translation and evaluation. I did not found anyone with that name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding information on German soldiers from World War I and World War II?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/finding-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii)

Comment: @WilliamKF Bavaria is specifically mentioned in the top answer.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl What about Austria records?

Comment: @WilliamKF No, hence me asking if it was a possible duplicate.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl Perhaps question just needs to be edited to focus on Austrian military records then?

Comment: @WilliamKF We need to hear from the OP -- Bavaria is where his ancestors were living at the time he's interested in.