# Searching for WW2 military record of German soldier who died 1945 in Italy?

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-2, italy

I have a name, place and date of birth, place and date of death also. This soldier died in Italy in 1945 and is buried in Futa Pass.

Could anybody provide me with where i can gain more information as to the records?

Comment: While you're waiting for a more specific answer, have you reviewed other questonos about german soldiers in ww2? http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-war-2+germany but http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-to-find-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii is particularly relevant

Answer (score 1):

The *[Deutschen Dienststelle (WASt)](https://www.dd-wast.de/en/home.html)* compiles service reports on  request. Please see [*How to find information on German soldiers from World War I and World War II?*](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-to-find-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii) on how to proceed and what to expect.