# Finding Listing of Polish Soldiers that were forced to fight with Germans in WWI?

Tags: germany, military-records, poland, world-war-1, 1910s

I need to locate a listing of Polish soldiers that were killed during WWI who were forced to fight with the Germans.

I had two of my grandfather's cousins "drafted" by the Germans during WWI to fight.

One was Edmund Roszczynialski who was a Priest and litter carrier during WWI.  Edmund was killed by the Wehrmacht on 11/11/1939 after Germany invaded Poland.

His brother Johan (Jan) Joseph Roszczynialski is the one am looking for.  He was supposedly killed between 1913 to 1915 but there is no confirmation of this.

Answer (score 4):

For your grandfather’s cousins the same research strategies apply as outlined in: *[How to find information on German soldiers from World War I and World War II?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-to-find-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii?rq=1)*

For this surname the Verlustlisten lists these entries:

- Roszczynialski, Johann (born 23 June in Liebenau, Tuchel (should be Gostycyn), slightly wounded in 1917, http://des.genealogy.net/search/show/7460457)
- Roszczynialski, Johann (born 23 June in Liebenau, Tuchel (should be Gostycyn), slightly wounded in 1918, http://des.genealogy.net/search/show/5632443)
- Roszczynialski, Josef (born 18 March 1890 in Lensitz, Neustadt (should be Łężyce), died from his injuries in late 1916 or early 1917 http://des.genealogy.net/search/show/5415439)

As I would expect spelling errors, I would also [search](http://des.genealogy.net/eingabe-verlustlisten/search/index) by place ("Ort") and use combinations like *Ros** when searching for the surname.