# Looking for grave of German soldier who died in World War II

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-2, burial-records

I'm looking to get the information about a German Soldier Grave and the name of the Cemetery.

The soldier's name was Michael Feichtenfchlader.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Your question is very brief so you may be asked to provide more details about Michael, but perhaps it is just enough to get an answer.  In the meantime you may find some of these Q&As interesting to review: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-war-2+germany?sort=votes

Comment: I would check your spelling of Michael's surname. I don't know much German but I can't imagine that Feichtenfchlader is the correct spelling. Maybe you meant the middle "f" to be an "s"?

Comment: Where do you think Michael died?

Comment: @HarryVervet This is actually a very common mistake when transscribing old Sütterlin handwriting (check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%BCtterlin , it shows three ways of writing the letter "s", one of which is surprisingly similar to an "f")

Comment: @Hazzit Yes, it is not only in German that the [long s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s) (ſ) is confused for an f.

Comment: In addition to the where is he is approximately believed to have died.. the question is when. A lot of soldiers didn't go into marked graves but if they did having the when and the approximately where might help locate it.

Answer (score 5):

The *[German War Graves Commission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_War_Graves_Commission)* (Volksbund) is the authority that maintains [a database of German war graves](http://www.volksbund.de/graebersuche.html) (especially World War I and World War II).

The only mandatory information you need for a search is the surname. (I would always start with a broad search and limit it down by given name or year of death later. Don’t search by date of birth or birthplace, as these information are often not available and thus you would exclude correct search results.)

“Feichtenfchlader” is not a German name (but “Feichtenschlager” is).

The [only Michael Feichtenschlager in the database](http://www.volksbund.de/graebersuche/detailansicht.html?tx_igverlustsuche_pi2%5Bgid%5D=6e4bd60aae85bb861a5b6d1ec3c8277f&cHash=2c7dbd666df6c0c5fac812fa3bf68179):

```
Nachname: Feichtenschlager
Vorname: Michael
Dienstgrad: Obergefreiter
Geburtsdatum: 01.12.1912
Geburtsort: Maria Schmoln
Todes-/Vermisstendatum: 14.02.1943
Todes-/Vermisstenort: Slawjansk am Donez
```

- Nachname = surname
- Vorname = given name
- Dienstgrad = rank
- Geburtsdatum = date of birth
- Geburtsort = place of birth
- Todes-/Vermisstendatum = place of death or place where soldier went missing
- Todes-/Vermisstenort = date of death or date when soldier went missing

The result also gives a short summary of the grave:

> Michael Feichtenschlager ist vermutlich als unbekannter Soldat 
>       auf die Kriegsgräberstätte Charkow überführt worden.
>       Grablage: wahrscheinlich unter den Unbekannten

It means: Most likely he is buried at Charkow cemetery, as his remains were not among those which could be identified.

The birth place is certainly misspelled, it should be [Maria Schmolln](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_Schmolln).

Please see also the following question:

- [How to find information on German soldiers from World War I and World War II?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-to-find-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii)

Comment: @Luc - In the Gräbersuche results, note the sentence "Nähere Informationen zu diesem Friedhof erhalten sie hier." as "hier" links to more information about the Charkow cemetery. Also, the annoying form asking for your personal information before showing results only has a few mandatory fields, and does not re-appear until the cookie that is set expires.