# Seeking WW2 death record in Russia for Paul Krahn who was born 1917 at Lauenburg (Germany)?

Tags: germany, death-records, world-war-2, russia

I had two uncles who both fell in WW2, one in Italy, who has a grave, but the other in Russia.

I only have his name (Paul Krahn), date and place of birth (2 Feb 1917 at Lauenburg, Germany) and that he was killed in action in Russia.

How can I find a more precise date and place of death for him?

Comment: I've made your question more focussed and hope that reflects the main piece of information that you are seeking.

Comment: Which Lauenberg? http://www.meyersgaz.org/search?search=Lauenburg

Answer (score 2):

Volksbund has no information in [its database of wargraves](http://www.volksbund.de/graebersuche.html) on Paul Krahn born in 1917. Your primary source of information should be Deutsche Dienststelle (WASt), as detailed in *[How to find information on German soldiers from World War I and World War II?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/how-to-find-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii)*. I would also request his birth certificate from local authorities, as it should contain hints on this death (when and where a death certificate was issued).

Please specify [which Lauenburg](http://gov.genealogy.net/search/name?name=Lauenburg) you mean.