# Looking for Ludwig Schermer, DOB 27 Dec 1917

Tags: germany, genealogical-societies

Ludwig was from Kaiserslautern, GE and said he was in the German Army. He was old enough for WWII, but not completely sure about when he served. He immigrated to USA in March 1957.

Comment: Ann, same question re Privacy Policy -- is Ludwig born after 1917 and still alive (or can you provide verifiable details of his death?)

Comment: The resources I've linked to from your other question may be of use for this one as well. Also very useful: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/finding-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii. I've suggested this is a duplicate because of the detailed answer over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this year of birth it is very likely that he served. Drafting for this year began in October 1938 and more than a third of the drafted servicemen died.

The service record should be available from [Deutschen Dienststelle (WASt)](https://www.dd-wast.de/en/home.html). This is your primary source for this kind of requests. Please see details for making a request here: [*Finding information on German soldiers from World War I and World War II?*](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/finding-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii/3917#3917). You are entitled to make a request if he is your ancestor. In case he is some other family member, you need a permission from his descendants to make a request. On the form (https://www.dd-wast.de/en/tracing-request/private-matters-research.html) you should pick all options as  “purpose”.