# Researching German relative in WWI

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-1, baden-wuerttemberg

I am trying to find out more about my German Great-grandfather who fought in (and survived) World War I.

I have [found a reference to his being badly injured](http://des.genealogy.net/search/show/5364217) on the 26th January 1917 in the German Casualty list but can't find out more information, for example, what regiment he served in. His record in the casualty list states that his rank was an NCO (Offizier Stellvertreter) and I have a photo of him in uniform but would love to find out more.

He was from Aglasterhausen, Baden.

Name Albert Hermann Schreiner, b. 7 August 1892

[image: Albert Schreiner]

Comment: Looks like your great-grandfather was quite a known person: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Schreiner 
I assume you already checked the literature available about him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add the photo to your post and if possible the name.

See this question for more information on German WWI soldiers: [*Finding information on German soldiers from World War I and World War II?*](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/finding-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii/3917#3917)

<s>The records from Württemberg and Baden are freely accessible online from the Landesarchiv Baden-Württemberg. Please see this introduction (in German): [*Soldaten im Ersten Weltkrieg  Findmittel zu den Personalunterlagen des XIV. Armeekorps im Generallandesarchiv Karlsruhe jetzt online*](http://www.landesarchiv-bw.de/web/soldaten_im_ersten_weltkrieg/54389). You choose the relevant time period for the personnel rosters and search them by unit (not indexed).</s>

His name is listed as part of *Sächsische Verlustliste Nr. 378*  (Saxon casulty list number 378). It seems he served in the military of the Kingdom of Saxony (maybe he moved to Saxony before the war).

According to the article [*Genealogische Quellen in den Militärbeständen des Hauptstaatsarchivs Dresden*](http://www.archiv.sachsen.de/genealogische-quellen-in-den-militarbestanden-des-hauptstaatsarchivs-dresden.html#article2339) from the state archive, there are no surviving personnel roster for this era. For officers, however, they state:

> Die gedruckten Ranglisten der sächsischen Armee von 1778 bis 1913 und die nachträglich erstellte Ehrenrangliste des deutschen Heeres 1914 bis 1918 enthalten die einzelnen Regimenter mit ihren Offizieren, aber auch Rang- und Nationallisten mit Dienstgraden, Geburtsort, Geburtsjahr und Laufbahn ebenso wie Informationen zur Geschichte der Regimenter, Uniformierung und Standorte. Die namentliche Erfassung von Offizieren begann bereits im Jahr 1632, die entsprechenden Listen befinden sich im Bestand 11246 Ranglisten.

(Printed ranking lists of the Saxon army from 1778 to 1913 and the "Ehrenrangliste" of the German army 1914 to 1918 contain individual regiments with their officers, but also ranking and other lists with ranks, place and date of birth, military career (…). The registration of officers by name started in 1632, these lists are kept in the inventory *[11246 Ranglisten.](http://www.archiv.sachsen.de/archiv/bestand.jsp?oid=02.03.08.01&bestandid=11246&syg_id=380778)*)

An inquiry with the archive might be helpful, as I can't tell you what is available and how it can be accessed.

The ancestry collection *[Deutschland, militärische Wochen- und Verordnungsblätter, 1816-1942](https://search.ancestry.de/search/DB.aspx?dbid=2199)* might contain your Great-grandfathers name because of promotions.

If he served in the Baden military earlier ([XIV Corps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XIV_Corps_(German_Empire))), the records are freely accessible online from the Landesarchiv Baden-Württemberg. Please see this introduction (in German): [*Soldaten im Ersten Weltkrieg  Findmittel zu den Personalunterlagen des XIV. Armeekorps im Generallandesarchiv Karlsruhe jetzt online*](http://www.landesarchiv-bw.de/web/soldaten_im_ersten_weltkrieg/54389). You choose the relevant time period for the personnel rosters and search them by unit (not indexed).

Comment: Many thanks @lejonet - have added name, DOB and photo to original post

Comment: Have checked out the resource listed as `GLA 456 E: Personalakten (1835-1949) mit 16.686 AE (85,50 lfd.m.)` but getting an error "Zu dieser URL existiert keine Ressource im Internetangebot des Landesarchivs Baden-Württemberg."

Comment: @ColeHenley I updated my answer. Please note, that  "26th January 1917" is the date of the list, not of the injury. This might have happend many months before.

Comment: Many thanks @lejonet for the further details - have contacted the archives at sachsen.de to see if they can shine any further light on my query