# Emil Fuchs military history from world war 1

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-1, bavaria

Looking for military  information, photos, rank, awards, duty stations, battles etc for Emil Fuchs. Born 7/25/1892, Deggendorf Germany.

Comment: If, after reviewing the advice in the duplicate, you find that you have a more focused question to ask about a particular aspect of Emil's military service, I encourage to [edit] this question to revise it.  That action will trigger a review, which should result in your question being re-opened.

Comment: As detailed in [Finding information on German soldiers from World War I and World War II?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/finding-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii) you are lucky, because Deggendorf is in Bavaria. Ancestry has three detailed entries on Emil Fuchs (all you ask for, except a photo) in its collection *Kriegsranglisten und -stammrollen des Königreichs Bayern, 1. Weltkrieg 1914-1918*.