# Family History Grandfather who served in 7th Panzer Division War Records

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-2

I am trying to locate my grandfather’s war records I have his service number his division & discharge papers. He was a POW in Algiers 1944. But I want  more information about where he was posted throughout WWII. Is there a database I can use to find this information?

Comment: Hi. If you look at https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/finding-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii/3917#3917 you'll find a wealth of information to help you with your research.

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy & Family History SE! The "official" post in the re-direct addresses German military records for individuals. There are also MANY books available on WWII unit histories, campaigns, etc.