# Finding World War 1 military record for Hauptmann Karl Stephan

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-1, records

Although my question doesn't concern my own genealogy I hope I can get some help or advice at this site.

I do a lot of research in Dutch archives especially on interned German soldiers and deserters and found a Hauptmann Karl Stephan who was wounded during the attack of his unit on Fort Pontisse near Liège. The Dutch Red Cross brought him to Holland where he eventually ended up in enternment .

His regiment was the Grossherzoglich Füselier Regimt Nr. 90 Kaiser Wilhelm.

I would like to find out more about him. Maybe a picture of him in uniform  and or military record.

But I have no experience in searching German record..

Comment: Hello, Raymond, and welcome.  I've tidied up your question a little to clear up few typographic oddities, and just want to check the sense of it: when you say "he eventually ended up in enternment" do you mean he was interned (imprisoned for the course of the war) or interred (buried)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding information on German soldiers from World War I and World War II?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/finding-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii) which you may find a good starting point in your search.

Comment: Hello, Raymond -- welcome to G&FH.SE! We are not a forum -- we are a question-and-answer site.  Your post doesn't have a question in it.  Generally speaking "I would like to find out more about him" is a goal, not a research question.  You can use the edit link below your question to edit and ask a more specific question.   The [tour] will show you how the site works, and you can find more information in the [help].

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me. What I meant was that he was imprisoned for the course of the war in Holland. And he was not amused by that. Accordong to the documents I found. I'll try reading the information mentioned by ColeValleyGirl first and rhn try to be more specific on my questoon.