# Finding grave of ancestor who died 1945 in Luckau, Brandenburg, Germany

Tags: germany, death-records, 1940s

I am looking for information on my great grandfather Friedrich Günther born July 15 1880, Sankt Johann,Saarbrücken,  and Died 1945 in Luckau, Brandenburg.

I don't know if he was in the Military but it could be possible.

Where could I find his grave and any details of service?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  We already have a [comprehensive answer on how to find WW2 German military records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/3917/19) so I think you should keep this question focused on finding your great grandfather's grave.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look on findagrave.com, but wasn't able to find your great-grandfathers grave, however, not all headstones are included, so that doesn't mean much.

It seems that there is only one cemetery in Luckau, so you could try contacting the city to see whether they have an index of who is buried where. The page [here](https://www.ortsdienst.de/brandenburg/dahme-spreewald/luckau/friedhofsamt/friedhofsverwaltung-luckau-inst449846/) includes an e-mail address you can try: stadt@luckau.de (though note that is is generic "city" address).

GoogleTranslate can help with writing an email to the city, alternatively, people on the [Genealogy Discord](https://discord.gg/Hb6Mb9z) or the [WikiTree Translation Team](https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Space:Germany_Project_Translation_Team) can help with translation.

Comment: Thank you, I speak and read German so that won't be a problem