# Military Records of Rudi Traute German Army Eastern Front WWII

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-2

I am looking for any information on Rudi Traute.  He was killed on the Eastern Front 16 April 1945.  I have attached a map showing were he was and what happened to him during WWII.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to ask a single focussed question rather than just posting a broad request for any information.

Comment: Without that I think it likely that your question will be closed as a duplicate of https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/finding-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii