# Finding German soldier records/lists

Tags: germany, military-records

I'm trying to find out if any of my German ancestors, served in the German military.

Is there any online site that holds listings of the names of soldiers and the  year(s) of service?

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/3915/2663

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding information on German soldiers from World War I and World War II?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/finding-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii)

Comment: Holly, this question needs a little more information to answer. As has been said, Germany did not exist in it's current form for most of the history of the region -- can you narrow it down to a region of Germany and/or a date range please. Use the edit button under your question to provide more detail.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such site.

Please bear in mind that „Germany“ was a patchwork of more or less independent states for most of its history. Written records are scattered over archives in different places. A lot of records are lost for a variety of reasons, including war.

You definitely need to focus your research efforts on specific individuals and then plan your research according to this individual‘s home country and period of time.

There is more regarding WWI and WWII here:

[Finding information on German soldiers from World War I and World War II?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/finding-information-on-german-soldiers-from-world-war-i-and-world-war-ii)